# Add new bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texlive

I want to use a bibliography style that not installed with texlive.
How could I install new bibliography style on texlive (windows 7)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the `bst` file for the new style into the same directory as your tex file then `(bib)TeX` will find it. Alternatively, you put the system directory containing the other bst files (for me this is `.../texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst`), but this will depend on your distribution.

Under UNIX there is also a `BIBTEX` environment variable, with similar syntax to `TEXINPUTS`, but I don't know the equivalent under windows. Setting thi allows you to put these files "anywhere" and still have bibtex and friends find the style.

After This, you must refresh the database of your texlive to where find everything. If you don't refresh the database the tex engine will not find this and other new files in the tex directory.

You can update your database by typing `texhash` in the Tex Live command-line.

Comment: I tried this, but I get this error: `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: doiTest.aux
I couldn't open style file ieeetr-faa.bst
---line 31 of file doiTest.aux
 : \bibstyle{ieeetr-faa
 :                     }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file doiTest.aux` where `ieee-faa.bst` is my new style.

Comment: @Masood Sorry I don't have access to a windows machine so I can't trouble shoot for you. Try searching for `plain.bst` and then put your file `ieee-faa.bst` into the same folder. Alternatively, since you're using texlive you should be able to find the top level `texlive` folder and then put the bst file into `.../texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst` as above.

Comment: @Masood In your texfile you have `\bibstyle{ieeetr-faa}` rather than `\bibstyle{ieeetr-faa :           }` as above right?

Comment: No, the `   :` is a part of the error message, not a part of the style name. The style exact name is: "ieeetr-faa".

Comment: If no window-wise person answers, and if the suggestions above don't work then you could try `\bibstyle{ieeetr-fa}`. This bst file seems to be part of the `TeXLive` distribution and it is presumably close to the one you want. Perhaps...

Comment: For me, the `BIBTEX` environment variable was not working (before I tried `TEXINPUTS`). But the man page came to the rescue: `BibTeX  searches  the directories in the path defined by the BSTINPUTS environment variable for .bst files. If BSTINPUTS is not set, it uses the system default.  For .bib files, it uses the BIBINPUTS environment variable if that is set, otherwise the default.  See tex(1) for the details of the searching.`

Comment: In case you're trying to load a local file, the bst file has to be in the directory where you're running `bibtex`, and not necessarily in the same directory as your tex file. Usually these would be the same, but it might differ if you're using a makefile from a parent directory.