# How to install the 'abstract' BibTeX style?

Tags: bibtex

How can I activate the BibTeX style `abstract`? I think with `\bibliographystyle`, but how to install it? It seems to be absent from my TeX Live installation.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of what you've got, and what exactly you're trying to achieve? A full MWE would be super. Also, what version of TeX Live (sic) are you using?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184410/add-new-bibliography-style is related. Usages examples and a download link are provided on https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-misc-abstract/.